# how to change a .net web service with JSON to wcf service?

Tags: .net, json, wcf, web-services

I want to change my previous .NET  web service into WCF Service, because I want my web service post the pure JSON variable for my android application.
Here is what I've done so far and I still get errors. How to fix this code?

my IService.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

public class Service : IService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "tampil")]
    public String GetReport()
    {
        List<Report> reports = new List<Report>();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnWf"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "select type, sum(OrderQty) as total from tbl_weeklyflash_ID where type <> 'NULL' group by type";
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Report report = new Report();
                report.type = reader["type"].ToString();
                report.total = reader["total"].ToString();
                reports.Add(report);
            }
        }

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Report[]));
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, reports.ToArray());
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

my Service.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

public class Service : IService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "tampil")]
    public String GetReport()
    {
        List<Report> reports = new List<Report>();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnWf"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "select type, sum(OrderQty) as total from tbl_weeklyflash_ID where type <> 'NULL' group by type";
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Report report = new Report();
                report.type = reader["type"].ToString();
                report.total = reader["total"].ToString();
                reports.Add(report);
            }
        }

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Report[]));
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, reports.ToArray());
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about to change it to the new WebApi instead of WCF ? WebApi has automatic content negotiation. which can recognize wether the client wants the data formated as XML oder JSON.
You can also selhost the webapi without needing iis or an asp website.

See for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/22/asp-net-web-api-content-negotiation-and-accept-charset.aspx
or http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2012/04/19/asp-net-web-api-how-content-negotiation-works.aspx

Comment: @BoasEnkler I'm still not understand :(